# Docker start issue

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-desktop

My docker desktop is not running, It's stuck in starting. Kindly clarity about WSL2

[image]

Comment: Please correct ALL CAPS, we assume you are SHOUTING at us.

Comment: Please read the tag info for docker (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker). Questions about Docker are okay but only if they are specifically related to software development. Problems just *running* Docker (or associated tools) belong elsewhere (such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reboot your computer and then run Docker, It will take some time to run at first because it depends on your system configuration and the internet connection.